# Issues with double estimation of SEM using lavaan.survey

Tags: survey, structural-equation-model

I am running a structural equation model with `lavaan.survey` package to account for complex survey design.

I have three latent and two manifest exogenous variables, and a manifest endogenous variable. All variables are ordinal.

I run sem with "DWLS" estimator followed by the same estimator with `lavaan.survey` function. This is giving me weird results, with large standard errors and p value close to 1.

I don't follow the 2-step estimation (with and without the survey procedure) employed in `lavaan.survey`. Do I need "DWLS" in both estimation steps. Or can I use robust Maximum Likelihood for the final estimation?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to R package or in Amos ?
As you know , Amos is best software for SEM.

Fouad, 
Statistical Consultant

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put your queries regarding the question in comment section. Answers block should only be used when you're confident about the solution of the problem. Or you have already tried the same that can help the asker.

Comment: I am referring to the R package. I have never used Amos.